# Telerik ASP.NET RadGrid is Ajax enabled but still does a postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am trying to make a RadGrid AJAX enabled so that when a user either sorts a column, or uses the "Paging" feature to go to the next page to see the next 10 rows in the grid, the page does not do a PostBack. However, even with the below config, it is still doing a page PostBack. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<div style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
        OnColumnCreated="RadGrid1_ColumnCreated" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="-1" 
        GridLines="Both" Skin="Black">
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you remove ***DefaultLoadingPanelID*** and ***UpdatePanelCssClass*** and try again?

Comment: No luck, still doing a PostBack.

Comment: Could you create a standalone ASPX page without master page and test it?

Comment: This is a standalone aspx page. I'm actually evaluating Telerik ASP.NET AJAX, and created a brand new WebForms project, and a single Default.aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Telerik Support, the script manager must be the first control on the form:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Telerik ASP.NET Example</title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadStyleSheetManager>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

You will also notice that I put the RadStyleSheetManager in the `<head>` section so it will render the `<link>` elements there, where they belong.